# Get a range of documents from mongo in ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Imagine I have 1000 documents in mongo. They are songs.

```
songs = @db["songs"].find()
```

Now I have a cursor to these songs. What if I want to get a specific range of these records, for example 31 - 40. (Note: 31 and 40 are not IDs or pertain to any field in the record, they are just being used like and index in an array of results)

In an array this would be easy

```
songs[31..40]
```

How can I do this in mongo / ruby?

Extra credit: would this solution be ok for millions of records?

Comment: You can use the cursor combo [**`limit()`**](https://goo.gl/lHC6lP) + [**`skip()`**](https://goo.gl/VgUux6) to achieve that but for millions of records performance is compromised since it gets slower as you increase the page number since skip() may become IO bound. Using skip requires the server to walk though all the documents (or index values) from 0 to the offset (skip) value. Consider using range-based pagination for these kinds of tasks. e.g if sorting by `"lastModified"` date you would simple pass the last `"lastModified"` value as the criteria for the query to get the next page of data.

Comment: @chridam can you show an example of limit() + skip()?

Answer (score 0):

the accurate query depends on what driver are you using, but in general stick to `$in` query (from mongo doc: `The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array`)

mongo console example
`db.inventory.find( { your_field_name: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )`

now try to translate it to your driver query [$in array should include your range]

Comment: yes, this works if you want to find a range with a given field, but i don't want to find a range in a given field, only in the returned results.